# Why does branching increase stability?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heat

The heat of combustion of neo- pentane is lower than n-pentane.This clearly means that neo-pentane is more stable than n-pentane.What is the reason for this?

Comment: You mean heat of formation! Neopentane can't be hydrogenated. In the future, you need to make an effort to address the issue. Try, https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/123093/deciding-the-order-of-heat-of-combustion-of-isomeric-alkanes/130811#130811

Comment: Sorry,i meant heat of combustion

Comment: [Deciding the order of heat of combustion of isomeric alkanes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/123093/deciding-the-order-of-heat-of-combustion-of-isomeric-alkanes).

Comment: If the heat of combustion of neopentane is lower than that of n-pentane, then that is a fact, but it doesn't necessarily mean that one is more stable than the other in a general sense. It is only more stable with respect to that specific reaction.